# positioning of page numbers

Tags: xetex

I'm trying to get the page number to a certain location on my page (a spesific location on the right corner) to fit into a template.

The best I could do so far is only change the location using this code:

```
\makepagestyle{outer}
\makeoddfoot{outer}{}{}{\color{white}\thepage}
\makeevenfoot{outer}{}{}{\color{white}\thepage}
\pagestyle{outer}
```

however this is still not yet where I would like the page numbers to be.

PS: I'm using memoir class.

Comment: And *where* should it be?

Comment: I would like it to be in a specific place  offset from where it is now in the bottom right corner. I have a template with a triangle on it, which should have the page number on it.

right now it is on it but too much to the side, so I would like to be able to center it. If this even possible.